# Heroku Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, heroku, deployment

My application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://<IP>/<name>
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
server.port=${PORT:8080}
```

My procfile

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT  -jar build/libs/restaurants-0.0.1- 
SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Error

```
2019-03-22T11:23:47.741653+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=restaurants-services.herokuapp.com request_id=91ae134c-60a0-4416-860c-b08b787e1be7 fwd="49.206.10.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-22T11:24:17.230083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2019-03-22T11:24:17.230261+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-03-22T11:24:17.385809+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-03-22T11:24:17.367612+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2019-03-22T11:24:18.386285+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=restaurants-services.herokuapp.com request_id=e3c2ccdd-2c62-4c56-aac6-0c5b36bbbe27 fwd="49.206.10.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-03-22T11:24:19.423553+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=restaurants-services.herokuapp.com request_id=f0e2e341-26c6-46b2-9f11-da129d752fba fwd="49.206.10.184" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Does `${PORT:8080}` have a special meaning to Spring? Because I don't think this will work if it's a regular environment variable. Try just `${PORT}`.

Comment: Does the app works locally if you build the jar and do `java -Dserver.port=8080  -jar build/libs/restaurants-0.0.1- 
SNAPSHOT.jar` ?

Comment: @Chris No, making ${PORT:8080} as {PORT} does not work.

Comment: @elias No it does not work in local also.

Comment: @VirendraSharma, to be clear, did you use `{PORT}` or `${PORT}`? Note that your database credentials will probably have to change, too, but that shouldn't cause this error. Can you share your web service code?